# C# and Java Generics

Tags: c#, generics, comparable

I'm trying export to C# from java prority queue algo. But there is problem with Comparable<> interface

java

```
public class MaxPQ<Key extends Comparable<Key>>
{
    private Key[] pq; // heap-ordered complete binary tree
    private int N = 0; // in pq[1..N] with pq[0] unused
    public MaxPQ(int maxN)
    { pq = (Key[]) new Comparable[maxN+1]; }
    //...
    private bool less(int i, int j) 
    { return pq[i].compareTo(pq[j]) < 0; }

}
```

c#

```
public class MaxPQ<Key> where Key : IComparable<Key>
{
    private Key[] pq; // heap-ordered complete binary tree
    private int N = 0; // in pq[1..N] with pq[0] unused
    public MaxPQ(int maxN)
    { pq = new Key[maxN + 1]; }
    //...
    private bool less(int i, int j) 
    { return pq[i].compareTo(pq[j]) < 0; }//Error

}
```

It throws error:
'Key' does not contain a definition for 'compareTo' and no extension method 'compareTo' accepting a first argument of type 'Key' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Please can you  solve this?!**

Comment: `CompareTo` instead of `compareTo` (mind the casing of the "C")?

Comment: Just a vague guess: CompareTo (with capital c) might work, according to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43hc6wht.aspx

Comment: Visual Studio makes it so easy for you. Intellisense shows all the members of an object when you type ".". A simple TAB key press completes the selected item of the intellisense list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `compareTo` to `CompareTo`.

Answer (score 0):

It's `CompareTo` in C#. Per the [Capitalization Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/ms229043%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), names of public methods are PascalCased:

> Do use Pascal casing for all public member, type, and namespace names consisting of multiple words.